# How to delete rows with updateBatch if I had a list and a single value for parameters?

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-batch, jdbctemplate

I have a list, which contains some name data:

```
List<String> names; //not null, already with values
```

And I have a single integer, which contains the ID of the created names:

```
Integer creatorId = 47;
```

And finally, I have the delete sql, which is like:

```
String deleteSql = "DELETE FROM persons WHERE person_name = ? and creator_id = ?";
```

The point here, is to use the `updateBatch` method from Spring, and **DO NOT USE** `in` clause in the delete sql for person_name-s, and **avoid** `for` loops.

Is there a way, to use some batch methods here?
Thank you!

Comment: Any reasons why you can't use a loop or an `in` clause?

Comment: this is some purpose in my job, to do it with batch, and not in clause. but if it is not possible, then I can do it different way. so is it possible to do it with batch, or no way?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Spring but you'd either have to create a single query using an in-clause or create a batch of queries by using a loop. I doubt you can reasonable do it without one of those (you might be able to pull something off with recursion but why?). I'd also doubt avoiding those without a good reason doesn't make sense from a business point of view.

Comment: I answered it, thank you. Somewhy I need to use batch methods if it is possible, rather than other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

```
public void delete(List<String> names, Integer creatorId) {
    List<Object[]> batchArgs = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String name : names) {
        batchArgs.add(new Object[] { name, creatorId });
    }
    jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("DELETE FROM persons WHERE person_name = ? and creator_id = ?", batchArgs);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that's using a for loop though. Wasn't your requirement to avoid them?

Answer (score 2):

Since you added "spring-batch" tag to this questions, here is how to do it with a spring-batch JdbcItemWriter:

```
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<T> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();

    writer.setDataSource(ds);
    writer.setSql("DELETE FROM persons WHERE person_name = ? and creator_id = ?");
    writer.setItemPreparedStatementSetter((dto, ps) -> {
        ps.setString(dto.getPersonName());
        ps.setInt(dto.getCreatorId());
    });

    writer.afterPropertiesSet();
```

This way, you are sure that the whole transaction handling is according to spring-batch, and moreover, jdbcItemWriter uses batchupdate methods.